# Format CSV out after parsing multiline JSON file

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, serialization

I have a JSON file like the following one (a smaller version):

```json
{
    "A001": {
        "X": 503744.7,
        "Y": 4726339.0,
        "Z": 458.84,
        "LON": -2.954286956913572,
        "LAT": 42.68952475979137,
        "dates": [
            "2015-01-01",
            "2015-01-02",
            "2015-01-03",
            "2015-01-04",
            "2015-01-05",
            "2015-01-06"
        ],
        "values": [
            "56.9",
            "49.7",
            "48.1",
            "37.1",
            "34.4",
            "35.9"
        ]
    },
    "A002": {
        "X": 607870.5,
        "Y": 4670754.0,
        "Z": 264.83,
        "LON": -1.69378623727067,
        "LAT": 42.18149989583031,
        "dates": [
            "2015-01-01",
            "2015-01-02",
            "2015-01-03",
            "2015-01-04"
        ],
        "values": [
            "287",
            "231",
            "207",
            "191"
        ]
    },
    "A403": {
        "X": 868708.0,
        "Y": 4709148.0,
        "Z": 849.0,
        "LON": 1.483146867002623,
        "LAT": 42.44694604132231,
        "dates": [
            "2015-01-01",
            "2015-01-02",
            "2015-01-03",
            "2015-01-04",
            "2015-01-05",
            "2015-01-06",
            "2015-01-07",
            "2015-01-08",
            "2015-01-09"
        ],
        "values": [
            "2.296",
            "7.033",
            "2.298",
            "2.275",
            "7.207",
            "5.456",
            "4.794",
            "4.24",
            "4.748"
        ]
    }
}
```

and I'm already able to read, parse and write each input key "A001", "A002", ... "A403" as a single .csv file

```py
from requests import get
from csv import DictWriter
import json

useful_columns = ["Station", "lon", "lat", "z", "dates", "values"]
default_value = ""

with open('station.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for json_obj in data:
        print(json_obj)
        filename = json_obj + '.csv'
    #data = json.load(json_file)['A001']
        lon = data[json_obj]["LON"]
        lat = data[json_obj]["LAT"]
        z = data[json_obj]["Z"]

        date = data[json_obj]["dates"]
        values = data[json_obj]["values"]
        #print(date)

        ## Open file for writing
        with open(filename, mode="w", newline='') as csv_file:

            # Create dictwriter object to use for writing
            writer = DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=useful_columns)
            # Write CSV headers
            writer.writeheader()
            ## Write each row to CSV file
            for item in data:
                print(item)
                row = {
                    "Station": item,
                    "lon": lon,
                    "lat": lat,
                    "z": z,
                    "dates": date,
                    "values": values,
                }
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The output I would like to have is a CSV file like the following example for `A001`:

```
Station,lon,lat,z,dates,values
A001,-2.954286957,42.68952476,458.84,2015-01-01,56.9
                                     2015-01-02,49.7
                                     2015-01-03,48.1
                                     2015-01-04,37.1
                                     2015-01-05,34.4
                                     2015-01-06,35.9
```

Now I have

```
['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06']
```

for dates and

```
['56.9', '49.7', '48.1', '37.1', '34.4', '35.9']
```

for values.

How can I transform the variables "dates2 and "values" as columns without apex as shown in the previous example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would like to have in the CSV file isn't a valid CSV file format because each row should have the same number of fields — but it's easy to rectify that by supplying a *`restval`* parameter value when creating the `csv.DictWriter` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)) that will be used for all the missing fields so the CSV files created will all be in a format similar to this for the `A001.csv` created:

##### Updated

For completeness, modified code to gracefully handle when a station has no data.

```
Station,lon,lat,z,date,value
A001,-2.954286956913572,42.68952475979137,458.84,2015-01-01,56.9
,,,,2015-01-02,49.7
,,,,2015-01-03,48.1
,,,,2015-01-04,37.1
,,,,2015-01-05,34.4
,,,,2015-01-06,35.9
```

Code to do it:

```
from csv import DictWriter
import json

CSV_FIELDNAMES = 'Station', 'lon', 'lat', 'z', 'date', 'value'

with open('station.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for station, json_obj in data.items():
        csv_filename = station + '.csv'
        with open(csv_filename, mode="w", newline='') as csv_file:
            try:
                date, *dates = json_obj['dates']
                value, *values = json_obj['values']
            except ValueError:
                print(f'{station} date values are empty')
                date, *dates = ['']
                value, *values = ['']

            # Initial full row of station data.
            row = {
                'Station': station,
                'lon': json_obj['LON'],
                'lat': json_obj['LAT'],
                'z': json_obj['Z'],
                'date': date,
                'value': value
            }

            writer = DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=CSV_FIELDNAMES, restval='')
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)  # Write initial full station data.
            writer.writerows({"date": date, "value": value}  # Write remaining rows.
                                for date, value in zip(dates, values))

print('fin')
```

Comment: for completeness, it could happen that some stations have date and value empty. If so it is enough to edit the previous code from @martineau adding the following line 

`with open(csv_filename, mode="w", newline='') as csv_file: 
if len(json_obj['dates'])==0: 
print(station+'_dates_values are empty')
row = { 'Station': station,'lon': json_obj['LON'],'lat': json_obj['LAT'],'z': json_obj['Z'],'date': '','value': ''}
writer = DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=CSV_FIELDNAMES, restval='')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(row)
else:..`

Comment: @sylar_80: I think cases of missing data could be handled more "pythonically" with less code — so have modified my answer to handle that situation to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

First write the first row that includes all the data:

```
for item in data:
    print(item)
    row = {
        "Station": item,
        "lon": lon,
        "lat": lat,
        "z": z,
        "dates": data[item]['dates'][0],
        "values": data[item]['values'][0],}
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Then write all the dates in the following rows:

```
    for i in range(1, len(data[item]['dates'])):
        row = {
            "Station": '',
            "lon": '',
            "lat": '',
            "z": '',
            "dates": data[item]['dates'][i],
            "values": data[item]['values'][i], }
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi @SiP I got the following error with your suggestion

´´´
"dates": item['dates'][0],  #"dates": date,
TypeError: string indices must be integers
´´´

Comment: @sylar_80, oops, I treated item as the value (and the key) at the same time. try to change to: data[item]['dates'][0]. I'll edit the answer